# what is the integer (number) equivalent to .text in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am trying to put a number from a textfield on a Parse database and I need to specify that it is a number. How can I do this?

I have done the equivalent with a string using `.text`

Comment: What? What database? `.text` of what?

Comment: a parse database. Of a `textfield`

Comment: You mean like `integerValue` on `NSTextFields`?

Comment: Where is the number coming from? Is it being entered in a text field (e.g. `UITextField`)? Is it coming from some other source?

Comment: @aapierce entered in a textfield

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the string value from the `UITextField` to a number, (e.g. `int`, `double`, or `NSNumber`).

```
NSString *textInput = myTextField.text;

int intValue = [textInput intValue];

NSNumber *age = [NSNumber numberWithInt:intValue];
user[@"age"] = age;
```

Comment: I am then wanting to put that into the database by doing this: `user[@"age"] = the_number_inserted_into_the_textfield;` how would I do this?

Comment: Wrap it into an NSNumber object using `@(intValue)` or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is unclear but I think you mean something like this:

```
UITextField *textField = ... // some text field
int age = [textField.text intValue];

user[@"age"] = @(age);
```